# Is there any limit on the number of Paypal Sandbox accounts that I can create?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm looking to set up around 200 accounts for beta testers of my application.  I can't find any information about a limit on the number of Sandbox Accounts that I can create.  Can anyone confirm if there is/isn't a limit?

Answer (score 0):

Well there isn't really an answer on what is the maximum limit number of sandbox account allowed to create.

To be honest, there isn't a need for 200 sandbox account to create in order to beta testing.

You can create just around 5 -10 accounts with all different countries account maybe and share the 10 accounts among 200 beta testers to test out.

In conclusion, my point is there isn't that much of 200 difference that you can create for 200 sandbox account.